# JSch Exception : Algorithm Negotiation fail error : JSCH version 0.1.55

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I am trying to do an SFTP through Java code using JSCH jar. The version of JSCH jar used is 0.1.55. Entry inside our pom.xml file is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.55</version>
</dependency>
```

The server I am trying to connect is a service exposed via a VPC Interface endpoint service provided by AWS. The client which is trying to do the SFTP through to this VPC is an EC2 instance.

The error I am encountering is

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:590)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:320)
```

The previous logs listing the different algorithms present on the server and client is

```
2019-03-14 08:50:54,501 INFO  [main]  Transporter - Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
2019-03-14 08:50:54,501 INFO  [main]  Transporter - Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
2019-03-14 08:50:54,501 INFO  [main]  Transporter - CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
2019-03-14 08:50:54,547 INFO  [main]  Transporter - CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
2019-03-14 08:50:54,590 INFO  [main]  Transporter - ecdh-sha2-nistp256 is not available.
2019-03-14 08:50:54,590 INFO  [main]  Transporter - ecdh-sha2-nistp384 is not available.
2019-03-14 08:50:54,590 INFO  [main]  Transporter - ecdh-sha2-nistp521 is not available.
2019-03-14 08:50:54,590 INFO  [main]  Transporter - CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
2019-03-14 08:50:54,592 INFO  [main]  Transporter - ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 is not available.
2019-03-14 08:50:54,593 INFO  [main]  Transporter - ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 is not available.
2019-03-14 08:50:54,593 INFO  [main]  Transporter - ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 is not available.
2019-03-14 08:50:54,593 INFO  [main]  Transporter - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
2019-03-14 08:50:54,593 INFO  [main]  Transporter - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
2019-03-14 08:50:54,593 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: server: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
2019-03-14 08:50:54,593 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: server: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
2019-03-14 08:50:54,593 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,arcfour
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,arcfour
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: server: 
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: server: 
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: client: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
2019-03-14 08:50:54,594 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
2019-03-14 08:50:54,595 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: client: none
2019-03-14 08:50:54,595 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: client: none
2019-03-14 08:50:54,595 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: client: 
2019-03-14 08:50:54,595 INFO  [main]  Transporter - kex: client:
```

As you can see in the above logs, the HostKeyAlgorithms on the VPC endpoint (server) are : **ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519** and the HostKeyAlgorithms on the EC2 instance (client) are : **ssh-rsa,ssh-dss**.

Since there is no common algorithm between the server and the client to perform host checking, it is failing by a Algorithm Negotiation fail.

The most suggested solution of installing the JCE unlimited strength policy files has been tried but didn't solve the issue. I installed the JCE policy jars in the location **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security** on the EC2 instance (client).

**Details about the code using JSCH for SFTP and further debugging inside JSCH jar.**

I ran the command

```
ssh -Q key
```

to get the available host key algorithms on the EC2 instance (client) environment. (This was done to confirm that the algorithms are present in the environment.) The output was

```
ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

A com.jcraft.jsch.Session object *mSession* is created and before calling the *mSession.connect(int timeOut)*, I printed the HostKeyAlgorithms present in the configuration of the mSession object using

```
mSession.getConfig("server_host_key")
```

The output was

```
ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
```

Inside the mSession.connect() call (this function call resides inside the JSCH jar), a function call *this.send_kexinit()* is made. Inside this send_kexinit() function, the below code is the one which is setting the final HostKeyAlgorithms.

```
String server_host_key = this.getConfig("server_host_key");
            String[] not_available_shks = this.checkSignatures(this.getConfig("CheckSignatures"));
            if (not_available_shks != null && not_available_shks.length > 0) {
                server_host_key = Util.diffString(server_host_key, not_available_shks);
                if (server_host_key == null) {
                    throw new JSchException("There are not any available sig algorithm.");
                }
            }
```

The checkSignatures() function is checking for the list of algorithms from this list *this.getConfig("CheckSignatures")* and checking if they are present or not. The checkSignatures() is as follows

```
private String[] checkSignatures(String sigs) {
        if (sigs != null && sigs.length() != 0) {
            if (JSch.getLogger().isEnabled(1)) {
                JSch.getLogger().log(1, "CheckSignatures: " + sigs);
            }

            Vector result = new Vector();
            String[] _sigs = Util.split(sigs, ",");

            for(int i = 0; i < _sigs.length; ++i) {
                try {
                    JSch var10000 = this.jsch;
                    Class c = Class.forName(JSch.getConfig(_sigs[i]));
                    Signature sig = (Signature)((Signature)c.newInstance());
                    sig.init();
                } catch (Exception var7) {
                    result.addElement(_sigs[i]);
                }
            }

            if (result.size() == 0) {
                return null;
            } else {
                String[] foo = new String[result.size()];
                System.arraycopy(result.toArray(), 0, foo, 0, result.size());
                if (JSch.getLogger().isEnabled(1)) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < foo.length; ++i) {
                        JSch.getLogger().log(1, foo[i] + " is not available.");
                    }
                }

                return foo;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

this.getConfig("CheckSignatures") function returned the list ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 and upon invocation of the above function on this list, the algorithms were not found as they are printed in the log as

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 is not available.
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 is not available.
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 is not available.
```

It is clear that the try block in the checkSignatures() function is where the call is failing and so they have been added to the **not available list**. Because of this, these 3 algorithms are removed from the list of HostKeyAlgorithms. So the list of

```
this.getConfig("server_host_key")
```

after going through the checkSignatures() method has only

```
ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

I am not able to understand why the try block is failing as in the com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.java file, the above 3 algorithms have been added in the configuration of JSch class.

```
config.put("CheckSignatures", "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521");
config.put("signature.dss", "com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureDSA");
config.put("signature.rsa", "com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureRSA");
config.put("keypairgen.dsa", "com.jcraft.jsch.jce.KeyPairGenDSA");
config.put("keypairgen.rsa", "com.jcraft.jsch.jce.KeyPairGenRSA");
config.put("keypairgen.ecdsa", "com.jcraft.jsch.jce.KeyPairGenECDSA");
config.put("ecdsa-sha2-nistp256", "com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA256");
config.put("ecdsa-sha2-nistp384", "com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA384");
config.put("ecdsa-sha2-nistp521", "com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA521");
config.put("server_host_key", "ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521");
```

and the classes named **com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA256**, **com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA384** and **com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA521** are present in their respective locations inside the jar file.

So it is not clear to me why the try block inside the checkSignatures() function is failing even though the classes are present inside the JSCH jar and the JCE unlimited strength policy files have been installed in the **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security** path properly. **(The policy files installed were for JDK 1.8 as our JDK version being used is 1.8)**

Can anyone help me understand why these algorithms **(ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521)(especially ecdsa-sha2-nistp256)** are coming out as not available. *(Since it is clear that addition of ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 to the list of available HostKeyAlgorithms on the client side would give a common algorithm for the server and client to negotiate.)*

**Edit:**

This issue got solved when we added Key Exchange Algorithms on the server side by the following line addition in the sshd_config file and restarting the sshd service.

```
KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

The algorithms `ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521` when added, made the error of

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 is not available.
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 is not available.
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 is not available.
```

go away. Still researching what the relation is between these Key Exchange algorithms and the HostKey algorithms.

Comment: Did you try constructing `com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA256` (and others) to see what specific exception does it throw?

Comment: Note that `ssh -Q key` does not tell you anything about what algorithms are available for JSch/Java -- that part of your question is imo irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: I didn't try constructing the `com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA256` class. Will try and see if the class construction is only failing or not. And i added the `ssh -Q key` part to show that the algorithms are present in the environment but are not picked up by JSch/Java @MartinPrikryl

Comment: Again, I do not think it's relevant. There's no *"environment"* shared by OpenSSH and JSch/Java.

Comment: I tried the below code to see if the class is being loaded properly as you suggested. `try
        {
            Class c = Class.forName("com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA256");
            System.out.println(c.getSuperclass().toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }`
and the output was `class com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSAN` So, the class is loading properly. It is not throwing any exception. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: I gave the hardcoded value here since the code `JSch.getConfig("ecdsa-sha2-nistp256")` returns the same value `com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA256` Could you suggest anything else that might be going wrong? @MartinPrikryl

Comment: OK, but try to **construct** the class instance as well: `c.newInstance()`.

Comment: Ran this code right after the above one. `Signature sig = (Signature)((Signature)c.newInstance());
            System.out.println(sig.toString());` and the output was `com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA256@42f30e0a` .

Comment: And `sig.init()`? Basically, you have to do all that `checkSignatures` does.

Comment: and did the sig.init() also. the whole code I ran was `try
        {
            Class c = Class.forName("com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA256");
            System.out.println(c.getSuperclass().toString());
            Signature sig = (Signature)((Signature)c.newInstance());
            System.out.println(sig.toString());
            sig.init();
            System.out.println(sig.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }`

Comment: and the whole output was `class com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSAN
com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA256@42f30e0a
com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureECDSA256@42f30e0a`

Comment: And i dont know if this is relevant or not. But im running this in a whole new file (and package) by importing the JSCH classes.

Comment: Hmm, then would will probably have to compile JSch code and add some additional logging to find out what's going wrong inside its code.

Comment: are you suggesting to get the source code of JSCH from git and add logging and make a custom jar and use it? sorry for asking such basic things. just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Could you point me to any resources which might help me understand the relation between Key Exchange Algorithms and Host Key Algorithms. I want to know this as adding Key Exchange algorithms `ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521` removed this error `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 is not available.
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 is not available.
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 is not available.`